# Filtering Spam-Tweets From the Tweepy Streaming API Output

Tags: python, streaming, tweepy

I have the following script that collects all the tweets that contain the search terms *$BTC* or *$ETH*

```
import sys
import time
import json
import pandas as pd
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

USER_KEY = ''
USER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
   tweet = json.loads(data)
   print(tweet)


def on_error(self, status):
   print(status)    
   return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
listener =  StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(USER_KEY, USER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(languages=['en'], track=['$BTC', '$ETH'], async=True)
```

The problem is that there is a lot of spam within the output. For example:

[image]

Ideally, I would like to filter out the spam. So I checked the JSON-output of these type of a tweets.

```
{
 'created_at': 'Fri Oct 05 07:09:19 +0000 2018',
 'id': 1048107851829452800,
 'id_str': '1048107851829452800',
 'text': 'Current $ARK price: $0.69 \n\nWe checked! Binance registration is 
  currently open    \n\n➡️ url_that_is_forbidden_by_stack_overflow… 
  url_that_is_forbidden_by_stack_overflow',
 'display_text_range': [
   0,
   140
  ],
 'source': '<a href="http://www.google.com" 
  rel="nofollow">medicinetoletitwin</a>',
 'truncated': True,
 'in_reply_to_status_id': None,
 'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None,
 'in_reply_to_user_id': None,
 'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None,
 'in_reply_to_screen_name': None,
 'user': {
  'id': 937395812748820480,
  'id_str': '937395812748820480',
  'name': 'Brenna ',
  'screen_name': 'BrennaPham',
  'location': 'San Jose, CA',
  'url': url_that_is_forbidden_by_stack_overflow,
  'description': 'Gamer ~',
  'translator_type': 'none',
  'protected': False,
  'verified': False,
  'followers_count': 168,
  'friends_count': 22,
  'listed_count': 2,
  'favourites_count': 17,
  'statuses_count': 12620,
  'created_at': 'Sun Dec 03 18:59:12 +0000 2017',
  'utc_offset': None,
  'time_zone': None,
  'geo_enabled': False,
  'lang': 'en',
  'contributors_enabled': False,
  'is_translator': False,
  'profile_background_color': 'F5F8FA',
  'profile_background_image_url': '',
  'profile_background_image_url_https': '',
  'profile_background_tile': False,
  'profile_link_color': '1DA1F2',
  'profile_sidebar_border_color': 'C0DEED',
  'profile_sidebar_fill_color': 'DDEEF6',
  'profile_text_color': '333333',
  'profile_use_background_image': True,
  'profile_image_url': 
  'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/939260582460506112/oltTD- 
   f1_normal.jpg',
  'profile_image_url_https': 
  'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/939260582460506112/oltTD- 
   f1_normal.jpg',
  'default_profile': True,
  'default_profile_image': False,
  'following': None,
  'follow_request_sent': None,
  'notifications': None
   },
 'geo': None,
 'coordinates': None,
 'place': None,
 'contributors': None,
 'is_quote_status': False,
 'extended_tweet': {
  'full_text': 'Current $ARK price: $0.69 \n\nWe checked! Binance 
   registration is currently open    \n\n➡️ 
   url_that_is_forbidden_by_stack_overflow\n\n$EOS $BCAP $RMC $TIME $RCN $XVC $PBL $BTC $WGR 
   $FLIXX $BTG $BCD $SMT $UKG $XWC $XEM $CRB $PASC $KMD $VIU $BNB $YOYOW 
   $INFX url_that_is_forbidden_by_stack_overflow',
  'display_text_range': [
   0,
   236
   ],
 'entities': {
  'hashtags': [],
  'urls': [
    {
      'url': 'url_that_is_forbidden_by_stack_overflow',
      'expanded_url': 'http://binance.com/?ref=10078236',
      'display_url': 'binance.com/?ref=10078236',
      'indices': [
        89,
        112
      ]
    }
  ],
  'user_mentions': [],
  'symbols': [
    {
      'text': 'ARK',
      'indices': [
        8,
        12
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'EOS',
      'indices': [
        114,
        118
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'BCAP',
      'indices': [
        119,
        124
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'RMC',
      'indices': [
        125,
        129
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'TIME',
      'indices': [
        130,
        135
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'RCN',
      'indices': [
        136,
        140
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'XVC',
      'indices': [
        141,
        145
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'PBL',
      'indices': [
        146,
        150
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'BTC',
      'indices': [
        151,
        155
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'WGR',
      'indices': [
        156,
        160
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'FLIXX',
      'indices': [
        161,
        167
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'BTG',
      'indices': [
        168,
        172
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'BCD',
      'indices': [
        173,
        177
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'SMT',
      'indices': [
        178,
        182
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'UKG',
      'indices': [
        183,
        187
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'XWC',
      'indices': [
        188,
        192
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'XEM',
      'indices': [
        193,
        197
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'CRB',
      'indices': [
        198,
        202
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'PASC',
      'indices': [
        203,
        208
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'KMD',
      'indices': [
        209,
        213
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'VIU',
      'indices': [
        214,
        218
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'BNB',
      'indices': [
        219,
        223
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'YOYOW',
      'indices': [
        224,
        230
      ]
    },
    {
      'text': 'INFX',
      'indices': [
        231,
        236
      ]
    }
  ],
  'media': [
    {
      'id': 1048107850399137792,
      'id_str': '1048107850399137792',
      'indices': [
        237,
        260
      ],
      'media_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DougiW1WwAA_8PZ.jpg',
      'media_url_https': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DougiW1WwAA_8PZ.jpg',
      'url': 'url_that_is_forbidden_by_stack_overflow',
      'display_url': 'pic.twitter.com/2Y1evrvz3x',
      'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/BrennaPham/status/1048107851829452800/photo/1',
      'type': 'photo',
      'sizes': {
        'thumb': {
          'w': 150,
          'h': 150,
          'resize': 'crop'
        },
        'large': {
          'w': 1920,
          'h': 1080,
          'resize': 'fit'
        },
        'medium': {
          'w': 1200,
          'h': 675,
          'resize': 'fit'
        },
        'small': {
          'w': 680,
          'h': 383,
          'resize': 'fit'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
},
'extended_entities': {
  'media': [
    {
      'id': 1048107850399137792,
      'id_str': '1048107850399137792',
      'indices': [
        237,
        260
      ],
      'media_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DougiW1WwAA_8PZ.jpg',
      'media_url_https': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DougiW1WwAA_8PZ.jpg',
      'url': url_that_is_forbidden_by_stack_overflow,
      'display_url': 'pic.twitter.com/2Y1evrvz3x',
      'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/BrennaPham/status/1048107851829452800/photo/1',
      'type': 'photo',
      'sizes': {
        'thumb': {
          'w': 150,
          'h': 150,
          'resize': 'crop'
        },
        'large': {
          'w': 1920,
          'h': 1080,
          'resize': 'fit'
        },
        'medium': {
          'w': 1200,
          'h': 675,
          'resize': 'fit'
        },
        'small': {
          'w': 680,
          'h': 383,
          'resize': 'fit'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
 },
'quote_count': 0,
'reply_count': 0,
'retweet_count': 0,
'favorite_count': 0,
'entities': {
 'hashtags': [],
 'urls': [
  {
    'url': 'url_that_is_forbidden_by_stack_overflow',
    'expanded_url': 'http://binance.com/?ref=10078236',
    'display_url': 'binance.com/?ref=10078236',
    'indices': [
      89,
      112
    ]
  },
  {
    'url': 'url_that_is_forbidden_by_stack_overflow',
    'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1048107851829452800',
    'display_url': 'twitter.com/i/web/status/1…',
    'indices': [
      114,
      137
    ]
  }
 ],
 'user_mentions': [],
 'symbols': [
  {
    'text': 'ARK',
    'indices': [
      8,
      12
    ]
  }
 ]
},
'favorited': False,
'retweeted': False,
'possibly_sensitive': False,
'filter_level': 'low',
'lang': 'en',
'timestamp_ms': '1538723359435'
```

I identified the following criteria to classify a tweet as spam:

- tweet['friend_count'] < 50
- tweet['followers_count'] > 50
- tweet['entities']['urls']['display_url'] contains link to specific spam-websites

As a result, I wrote a new function in the script:
import sys
    import time
    import json
    import pandas as pd
    from tweepy import OAuthHandler
    from tweepy import Stream
    from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

```
USER_KEY = ''
USER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''
spam = ['spam_website_1', spam_website_2', 'spam_website_3']

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
   tweet = json.loads(data)
   self.filter_tweet(tweet)


def filter_tweet(self, tweet):
    url = data['entities']['urls']['display_url'] if 'display_url' in 
    data['entities']['urls'] else None
    if len(url) != 0):
       if data['user']['friends_count'] < 50:
          if data['user']['followers_count'] < 50:
              if any(x in url for x in spam):
                pass
    else:
       print(tweet)

def on_error(self, status):
   print(status)    
   return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
listener =  StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(USER_KEY, USER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(languages=['en'], track=['$BTC', '$ETH'], async=True)
```

I would like to know if this part is fast enough for the Streaming API output or should be rewritten. Is it possible to write this more elegantly and faster?

```
 if len(url) != 0):
       if data['user']['friends_count'] < 50:
          if data['user']['followers_count'] < 50:
              if any(x in url for x in spam):
                pass
```

Answer (score 1):

As a comment, you wrote `tweet['followers_count'] > 50` then `data['user']['followers_count'] < 50` in the code.

Filtering spam is a hard job, i guess even Twitter can't solve it.
I don't think this is a question about followers or friends count.
And even if you write a black list of scam and spam sites, it will change every day.
Maybe you could also make a black lists of users.

According to me, `if` tests are very fast (i have some experience with chess programming). So, yes you can check while streaming.
But if your tests will grow, then you may push directly tweets without any process, for example in Redis. Then another script (worker) can do the job to get out tweets from redis and make spam tests.

EDIT : another idea for spam criteria : the number of tweets posted per day. The user you gave as an example is publishing nearly 42 tweets per day. So a test could be `if tweetsPerDay > 10: spam`. (I get this count number with the user account created at and the date now, converted to days, and the total tweets count, then calculate the average). But it may be not very accurate, like checking followers and friends count.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to filter Spam:

1. **Machine Learning/Deep Learning**: You require labeled data (some data needs to be already marked as spam)
2. **Keyword Filtering**: Here are some exemplary keywords

   {
   "spam_keywords": [
   "Act now!",
   "Apply now!",
   "Call now!",
   "Don't hesitate!",
   "For only",
   "Get started now",
   "Limited time",
   "Great offer",
   "Instant",
   "Now only",
   "Offer expires",
   "Once in a lifetime",
   "Order now",
   "Order today",
   "Special promotion",
   "Urgent",
   "While supplies last",
   "Bonus",
   "All new",
   "Amazing",
   "Certified",
   "Congratulations",
   "Fantastic deal",
   "For free",
   "Guaranteed",
   "Outstanding value",
   "Risk free",
   "Satisfaction guaranteed",
   "Free",
   "Free!",
   "Free trial",
   "Free consultation",
   "Free gift",
   "Free membership",
   "Free offer",
   "Free preview",
   "Free sample",
   "Free quote",
   "Sign up free today",
   "Deal",
   "Giving away",
   "No obligation",
   "No strings attached",
   "Offer",
   "Prize",
   "Trial",
   "Unlimited",
   "What are you waiting for?",
   "Win",
   "Winner",
   "You're a winner!",
   "Won",
   "You have been selected",
   "#1",
   "100% free",
   "100% satisfied",
   "50% off",
   "One hundred percent guaranteed",
   "Click below",
   "Click here",
   "Increase sales",
   "Increase your sales",
   "Opt in",
   "Open Sale",
   "Sales",
   "Subscribe",
   "Chance",
   "Sample",
   "Satisfaction",
   "Solution",
   "Success",
   "Cards accepted",
   "Full refund",
   "Affordable",
   "Bargain",
   "Best price",
   "Cash",
   "Cash bonus",
   "Cheap",
   "Credit",
   "Discount",
   "For just",
   "Lowest price",
   "Save big money",
   "Why pay more?",
   "Buy",
   "As seen on",
   "Buy direct",
   "Clearance",
   "Order",
   "$$$",
   "Marketing solutions",
   "Join millions",
   "Name brand",
   "No questions asked",
   "Giving it away",
   "Best rates",
   "Compare",
   "Drastically reduced",
   "Exclusive deal",
   "Magic",
   "Miracle",
   "Revolutionary",
   "Secrets",
   "This is not spam",
   "You won't believe",
   "Risk-free investment",
   "Money-back guarantee",
   "Act immediately",
   "Limited offer",
   "Serious cash",
   "Fast cash",
   "Save up to",
   "Cancel at any time"
   ]
   }
3. **Analyzing Tweet Characteristics**: Here are some exemplary characteristics

   {
   "Profile": [
   "Age of an account",
   "Number of followers",
   "Number of following/friends",
   "Number of favorites",
   "Number of lists",
   "Number of tweets",
   "Reputation score",
   "Following to followers ratio (FIFO)",
   "Followers ratio",
   "Following ratio",
   "Followers' following to followers ratio",
   "Followers based reputation Score",
   "Length of Profile description",
   "Length of Profile name",
   "Presence/absence of Profile image",
   "Number of tweets posted per day"
   ],
   "Content": [
   "Average tweets length",
   "Number of hashtags",
   "Number of hashtags per tweet",
   "Number of URL links",
   "Number of URL links per tweet",
   "Number of unique URL links per tweet",
   "Number of user mentions",
   "Number of user mentions per tweet",
   "Number of unique user mentions per tweet",
   "Number of spam words",
   "Number of spam words per tweet",
   "Number of words",
   "Number of re-tweets",
   "Number of re-tweets per tweet",
   "Number of user replies",
   "Number of user replies per tweet",
   "Number of characters per tweet",
   "Number of digits per tweet",
   "Number of keywords per tweet",
   "Tweet similarity",
   "Zip compression ratio of posted tweets",
   "Text to link ratio",
   "Repeated words",
   "Content and hashtags similarity ratio",
   "Comments ratio",
   "Average spam post count",
   "Different descriptions from tweets",
   "Different following interests from tweets",
   "Friends' name similarity",
   "Tweet Time pattern"
   ],
   "Graph": [
   "Bi-directional link ratio",
   "Betweenness centrality",
   "Clustering co-efficient",
   "Sender social degree",
   "Interaction history",
   "Cluster size",
   "Community based reputation",
   "Community based cluster coefficient",
   "Average neighbors' followers",
   "Average neighbors' tweets",
   "Following to median neighbors' followers"
   ],
   "Automation": [
   "API ratio",
   "API URL ratio",
   "API tweet similarity",
   "Automated tweet ratio",
   "Automated tweet URL ratio",
   "Automated tweet similarity"
   ],
   "Time": [
   "Tweet Time standard deviation",
   "Tweet Time interval standard deviation",
   "Standard deviation of numerical IDs of followings",
   "Standard deviation of numerical IDs of followers",
   "Mean Time between tweets",
   "Standard deviation Time between tweets",
   "Idle duration Time between tweets",
   "Change rate of number of followings"
   ]
   }

The bigram similarity is very accurate when it comes to identifying spam as you can identify a high similarity between tweets, making it very likely that they are spammed. Before, you should also filter out retweets. Here is some code for it ('item_number' is the user ID):

```
def calculate_bigram_similarity(bigrams1, bigrams2):
    """Calculate bi-gram similarity using precomputed bigrams."""
    intersection = sum((bigrams1 & bigrams2).values())
    total = sum(bigrams1.values()) + sum(bigrams2.values()) - intersection
    return intersection / total if total else 0

from collections import Counter
def generate_word_bigrams(text):
    words = text.split()  # Split the text into words
    return [tuple(words[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(words) - 1)]  # Generate word bi-grams

def calculate_bigram_similarity(text1, text2, letter_bigrams=False):
    if letter_bigrams:
        # Generate bigrams for each string
        bigrams1 = [text1[i:i+2] for i in range(len(text1)-1)]
        bigrams2 = [text2[i:i+2] for i in range(len(text2)-1)]
    else: 
        # word bigrams
        # Generate word bi-grams for each string
        bigrams1 = generate_word_bigrams(text1)
        bigrams2 = generate_word_bigrams(text2)

    # Count bigrams
    bigrams1_count = Counter(bigrams1)
    bigrams2_count = Counter(bigrams2)

    # Calculate intersection and total
    intersection = sum((bigrams1_count & bigrams2_count).values())
    total = sum(bigrams1_count.values()) + sum(bigrams2_count.values()) - intersection

    return intersection / total if total else 0

def preprocess_text(text):
    """Convert text to lowercase."""
    return text.lower()

def filter_spam_tweets(data):
    non_spam_data = pd.DataFrame()
    users_to_drop = set()

    for user_id, group in data.groupby('item_number'):
        if user_id in users_to_drop:
            continue

        # Preprocess tweets to lowercase before comparison
        tweets = [preprocess_text(text) for text in group['text'].tolist()]
        spam_found = False

        for i in range(len(tweets)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(tweets)):
                similarity = calculate_bigram_similarity(tweets[i], tweets[j], letter_bigrams=False)
                if similarity > 0.8:
                    users_to_drop.add(user_id)
                    spam_found = True
                    break
            if spam_found:
                break

        if not spam_found:
            non_spam_data = pd.concat([non_spam_data, group], ignore_index=True)

    return data[~data['item_number'].isin(users_to_drop)]
```

Sources:
Alom, Z., Carminati, B., and Ferrari, E. 2020. “A Deep Learning Model for Twitter Spam Detection,” Online Social Networks and Media (18), Elsevier, p. 100079.
Varol, C., and Tareq Abdulhadi, H. M. 2018. Comparision of String Matching Algorithms on Spam Email Detection.
Lambert, A. 2024. “100 Spam Trigger Words to Avoid in 2024,” Lix Blog. (https://lix-it.com/blog/spam-trigger-words/, accessed February 3, 2024).
Mccord, M., and Chuah, M. 2011. Spam Detection on Twitter Using Traditional Classifiers.
Alhassun, A. S., and Rassam, M. A. 2022. “A Combined Text-Based and Metadata-Based Deep-Learning Framework for the Detection of Spam Accounts on the Social Media Platform Twitter,” Processes (10:3), MDPI.
Berker, B. 2017. “Twitter Spam Detector: Python Script That Uses Bayesian Probability Machine Learning Techniques to Detect Given Tweet/Text,” GitHub. (https://github.com/berkerbugur/twitter-spam-detector, accessed February 3, 2024).
Wu, T., Liu, S., Zhang, J., and Xiang, Y. 2017. “Twitter Spam Detection Based on Deep Learning,” ACM International Conference Proceeding Series, Association for Computing Machinery.
Rodrigues, A. P., Fernandes, R., Aakash, A., Abhishek, B., Shetty, A., Atul, K., Lakshmanna, K., and Shafi, R. M. 2022. “Real-Time Twitter Spam Detection and Sentiment Analysis Using Machine Learning and Deep Learning Techniques,” Computational Intelligence and Neuroscience (2022), Hindawi Limited.
Crypto Advice. 2023. “How Does Twitter Identify a Tweet or Comment as Spam?,” Quora. (https://www.quora.com/How-does-Twitter-identify-a-tweet-or-comment-as-spam, accessed February 4, 2024).
Abkenar, S. B., Kashani, M. H., Akbari, M., and Mahdipour, E. 2020. Twitter Spam Detection: A Systematic Review.
Chen, C., Wang, Y., Zhang, J., Xiang, Y., Zhou, W., and Min, G. 2015. “Statistical Features Based Real-Time Detection of Drifted Twitter Spam,” IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON INFORMATION FORENSICS AND SECURITY (X), p. 1.